# Git gives me the famous 500 error

Tags: android, git

I'm really confused about this issue :

I push my project to git but it gives me that error :

> 500 We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> Please contact your GitLab administrator if this problem persists.

my project is some android's libraries, his size 38 Mo, I look for to my problem, and all solutions are modifiy the server's configuration (.htaccess) 
I push the same project another time but always the same error, can you help me ?

Comment: Check your server's error logs for the exact issue

Comment: I try `git log` but the giving information not important (author date ...), what do you think ?

Comment: no not that.. I meant the gitlab error logs . It uses nginx so I guess they would be at `/var/log/nginx` on the server where gitlab is installed

Comment: the server in another country, I hadn't acces... I could just push pull commit ... thank's bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem inside my libs, I found a file it looks like it was a depot in Git, I delet the founded .git .gitigone and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the branch you want to push to is protected in gitlab?
You can control this under Project->Settings->Protected Branches.

Comment: yes I unpretect the branch but always the same error, I must commit and push it again to verify ?

Comment: If you already commited in your local repositiory a simple push should do the trick.